# What should be the return type of the following function template with multiple parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

What should be the return type of the following function template-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T1, class T2>
returntype biggerNum(T1 num1 , T2 num2){
    if(num1>num2)
        return num1;
    return num2;
}

int main(){
    cout<<biggerNum(2,3.4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare, `std::min` and `std::max` had the same question and already have an answer to it. Short answer: they don't allow two input types, only one.

Comment: You could force the function parameters to be the same type, then it is down to the caller to do any conversions explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

Since both types will need to be convertible to some common type, you can use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to get the common type between `T1` and `T2` like

```
template <class T1, class T2>
std::common_type_t<T1, T2> biggerNum(T1 num1 , T2 num2){
    if(num1>num2)
        return num1;
    return num2;
}
```

If there is no such type, then you will get a compiler error.

Comment: You meant `std::common_type_t`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution mentioned in the comments is to force the parameters to be only one type:

```
template <class T>
T biggerNum(T num1, T num2){
    if(num1>num2)
        return num1;
    return num2;
}
```

This would force the conversion on the user side, like `std::min` and `std::max`:

```
float a = 9;
int b = 8;
biggerNum(a, static_cast<float>(b));
```